# get data from related tables to vuejs component in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, uiviewcontroller, laravel-blade

My vue component that loads as **sidebar** in each view, uses the 3 levels objects and im going to fill it based on database data dynamically

```
data() {
    return {
        collection: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "Blue Collection",
                categories: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        title: "Large Format",
                        items: [
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                title: "BL 250",
                            },
                            {
                                id: 2,
                                title: "BL 260",
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        title: "Small Format",
                        items: []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "Lavender Collection",
                categories: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        title: "Medium Format",
                        items: []
                    },
                    {
                        id: 2,
                        title: "Small Format",
                        items: []
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: "Violet Collection",
                categories: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        title: "Large Format",
                        items: [
                            {
                                id: 1,
                                title: "VL 400",
                            },
                            {
                                id: 2,
                                title: "VL 420",
                            },
                            {
                                id: 3,
                                title: "VL 300",
                            },
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
        ],
    }
},
```

how can i have empty `collection: []` at start which fills based on current database tables dynamically

my current tables model

```
// Grand Parent
class Collection extends Model
{
    public function categories() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category', 'collection_id');
    }

    public function items() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Item', 'App\Category');
    }
}


// Parent
class Category extends Model
{
    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'category_id');
    }

    public function collection() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Collection');
    }
}


// Child
class Item extends Model
{
    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

and i have no idea about correct `Controller` since it is a part of view as sidebar

```
class CollectionController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $collection = Collection::with('categories')->get();

        // according to sidebar position which uses in all pages, which view needed or is it correct way to load data here?
        return view('???')->with(['collection' => $collection]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would avoid calling it collection, I would call ColorCollection the model

Comment: Use nested map function to fill the data object in Vue. It would be helpful if you could show what are you getting from the controller.

Comment: Another thing if you are using Laravel for backend data management. Then you don't need to `return view()`. Just `return $collection;` access the route by vue-resource or axios.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, Im using laravel as backend, i mean how to put returned data from controller into collection array as hierarchy mentioned in component

Comment: You are going to want to make /api/someendpoint  to handle axios calls from vue to grab collections dynamically.  mounted()

Comment: Tq @Cameron, I have no problem to get data by axios, I want to know how use children of parents as related tables in axios response, coz `axios.get('/api/data').then(response => console.log(response.data)});` returns all data in "Category" table (as grand parent), so i need to create nested object in vue component based on relateions on tables

Comment: my data controller: `class DataController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {

        return Category::all();

    }
}`

Comment: I have always passed props to child components and used :key  to update the child component.  Not sure if that's what you are asking but  in theory when you update the parent and pass a prop and the key changes it should update the child.